# Assigning new property to object using deconstruction

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am reviewing a PR and i found the follwing choice for assigning a new property to an object.

```
foo = { 
  ...foo, 
  bar: "value" 
};
```

And im wondering if there is any advantage of doing that instead of just going for

```
foo.bar= "value";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. By doing it the way you showed, you will be creating a brand new object in memory, rather than mutating the existing one. In other words, this is an immutable operation.

The usual reason for doing immutable operations is that it enables faster equality checking, because it is just a single reference check, as opposed to having to deeply compare all the properties of the objects.

Comment: Oh! I see! That was very useful! Thanks @GregL!!

Comment: So..is it expected to be used every time like this? We should totally ditch the other assignment form?

Comment: @dwaksman It depends on your use case. If you are using a Flux/Redux style of state library, doing immutable operations is virtually required for various reasons that are easily researched. But in other cases, especially if you aren't comparing old and new values, mutating the existing object might be fine (and faster).